# CCA canonical coefficient is more than $1$?

Tags: correlation

So I have performed CCA in Rstudio and got my $A=(S_{xx}^{-1/2})\cdot S_{xy}\cdot(S_{yy}^{-1/2})$ matrix and used commands to get its Singular value decomposition.

Yet the first coefficient comes out to be approx. $13.08$

What does this result imply?

I thought they had to be $<1$